# Call $created variable in content type node template

Tags: 7, theming, nodes, datetime

How can I call the $created variable in my content type node template? I tried the following but it just produces what seems to be a random string of numbers:

```
        <?php print render($created); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$created` variable is just a number, but it's not random it is a [unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) of the node created date.

Since it is not a [render array](https://www.drupal.org/node/930760) you do not print it using the [render()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/render/7) function, you would just print it like this:

```
<?php print $created; ?>
```

However that is also probably not what you want because you probably want a human readable date/time, not a unix time stamp.

As you can see in the main variable preprocess function for the node template ([template_preprocess_node()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7)), there is also a variable `$date`, which is a formatted date based on the `$created` variable.
That will default to using your website's medium date format.

You can use it like this:

```
<?php print $date; ?>
```

If that is not the format you want you can also manually use the [format_date()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/format_date/7) function to format it to your requirements like this:

```
<?php print format_date($created, 'short'); ?>
```

or like this for something more custom:

```
<?php print format_date($created, 'custom', 'd/m/Y'); ?>
```

See the [php date() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for more information on custom date format options.

Answer (score 0):

This can vary from theme to theme so you can look in your template.php for the [hook_preprocess_node()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7). This is where you can alter and set variables for your node.tpl.php. The $submitted variable could be used or modified in this case.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_node().
 */
function my_theme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  // Alter the submitted variable, just on blog type.
  if ($variables['type'] == 'blog') {
    $variables['submitted'] = format_date($variables['created']);
  }
  // Or define a new variable for your node.tpl.php
  $variables['created_date'] = format_date($variables['created']);
}
```

Print the variable in your node.tpl.php

```
<?php print $created_date ?>
```